# Can a failed SSD not show up in lsblk?

Tags: ssd

I'm trying to determine condition of a laptop's SSD. Booted up live Ubuntu.

If SSD broke down does it mean it won't show up on any software tests like if it wasn't even plugged in? Or does the absence of SSD and its partitions mean only that there literally is no SSD in this computer?

Comment: `lsblk` is rather high level. Check `dmesg` to see if Linux had trouble detecting the disk. But yes, a malfunctioning device may appear absent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If SSD broke down does it mean it won't show up on any software tests like if it wasn't even plugged in?

- Make sure the power cable is connected
- Try different SATA port and make sure it is not an issue with port or motherboard.
- A failed firmware update could "brick" the drive, and the situation you describe is a possibility.
- Some drives, when they reach their limit of write endurance, will basically "brick" themselves.  [Reference](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead).

If the device is detected, `lsblk` should show it even if it's unpartitioned (you'd only see the `/dev/sda` for example and not any `/dev/sda1`, etc.)